# Generating a dynamic pivot table for student marks to create a scoresheet

Tags: php, mysql, database, analytics, dynamic-pivot

I have a school management system that calculates student marks and then prints out reports.
I want to also create a pivot table that shows student marks for a specific class
but the pivot should be able to show dynamically the scores of the students and the subjects he/she is doing

I have 3 tables
Marks->Stores student marks

Subject->stores subjects

Students->stores students

StudentXClass->stores class student is in

```
 Marks table

 id| student_id | class_id | subject_id | mark
  2    st323         1          2          49
  3    st324         1          2          45
  4    st632         1          3          56
```

Subjects Table

```
  subject_id| subject_name    
     1        Maths
     2        Economics
     3        English
```

Students Table

```
  student_id| student_name    
    st323        Smith Joe
    st324        Sam Doe
    st632        Laura Dan
```

Class Table

```
  class_id| class_name    
     1        Grade 1
     2        Grade 2
     3        Grade 3
```

StudentxClass Table

```
  class_id| student_id    
     1        st323
     1        st324
     1        st632
```

I want to create a pivot table that will tabulate a scoresheet for the students like:

```
Student Name| Subject | Subject| Subject| Subject
Smith Joe      mark      mark     mark    mark
Sam Doe        mark      mark     mark    mark
Laura Dan      mark      mark     mark    mark
```

Comment: What is your question? How to do the `query` ? or how to echo the `pivot` table?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) AND consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @BurhanKashour how to do the query, if it is queried properly I think it will be easy to echo the pivot table using PHP